# Calculate the number of pixels inside a shape drawn on HTML5 canvas?

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am using [sketch.js](http://intridea.github.com/sketch.js/) to dynamically draw very simple shapes on HTML5 canvas.

Is there a way to calculate the number of pixels inside a closed shape drawn on the canvas?

Comment: Not easily. You could somehow divide it up into small trapeziums and approximate it, but it isn't built in at all.

Comment: Yes, I was surprised by the lack of documentation for accomplishing this — not for sketch.js, but for canvas. Oh well — thanks.

Comment: When you say "number of pixels" do you mean you want to know the size of its bounding box or you literally want to know the number of non-transparent pixels?

Comment: The literal number of non-transparent pixels.

Comment: @markE, Isn't that the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here's how you count non-transparent pixels on a canvas**

```
// get a reference to your canvas
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

// get the pixel data from the canvas
var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height);

// loop through each pixel and count non-transparent pixels
var count=0;
for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4)
  {
      // nontransparent = imgData.data[i+3]==0
      if(imgData.data[i+3]==0){ count++; }
  }
```

**[Edited: to get pixel count of "if-filled" closed shapes on a canvas]**

I usually use this code to do masking in canvas, but I’ve adapted it here to get your pixel count inside your closed shape.

A few caviats:

Because of the “neighboring” algorithm being used, the strokewidth must be at least 2 pixels wide for uncurved shapes and at least 3 pixels wide for shapes containing curves.

Because Canvas automatically draws strokes with anti-aliasing, the inside pixel count will always be slightly larger than expected.  This is because anti-aliasing “eats into” the stroke, effectively causing more inside pixels than expected.  BTW, there is *no way* to turn off canvas’s anti-aliasing, if you try getImageData(), setting all shape pixels to rbg(0,0,0), putImageData(),  the resulting image will also be  anti-aliased—just more jagged!

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

//  The floodFill algorithm below is based on the good work by William Malone, Copyright 2010 William Malone (www.williammalone.com) -- Apache License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 -- Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
    var strokeColor =  {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0};
    var fillColor =  {r: 101,g: 155,b: 65};
    var fillData;
    var strokeData;

    function redraw() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        context.putImageData(fillData, 0, 0);
        drawOutline(context);
    }

    function matchstrokeColor(r, g, b, a) {
      // must check for near black because of anti-aliasing
      return (r + g + b < 100 && a === 255);  
    }

    function matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB) {

      var r = strokeData.data[pixelPos],
        g = strokeData.data[pixelPos + 1],
        b = strokeData.data[pixelPos + 2],
        a = strokeData.data[pixelPos + 3];

      // If current pixel of the outline image is black-ish
      if (matchstrokeColor(r, g, b, a)) {
        return false;
      }

      r = fillData.data[pixelPos];
      g = fillData.data[pixelPos + 1];
      b = fillData.data[pixelPos + 2];

      // If the current pixel matches the clicked color
      if (r === startR && g === startG && b === startB) {
        return true;
      }

      // If current pixel matches the new color
      if (r === fillColor.r && g === fillColor.g && b === fillColor.b) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    function setPixel(pixelPos, r, g, b, a) {
      fillData.data[pixelPos] = r;
      fillData.data[pixelPos + 1] = g;
      fillData.data[pixelPos + 2] = b;
      fillData.data[pixelPos + 3] = a !== undefined ? a : 255;
    }

    function floodFill(startX, startY, startR, startG, startB) {

      var newPos;
      var x;
      var y;
      var   pixelPos;
      var   neighborLeft;
      var   neighborRight;
      var   pixelStack = [[startX, startY]];

      while (pixelStack.length) {

        newPos = pixelStack.pop();
        x = newPos[0];
        y = newPos[1];

        // Get current pixel position
        pixelPos = (y * canvasWidth + x) * 4;

        // Go up as long as the color matches and are inside the canvas
        while (y >= 0 && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
          y -= 1;
          pixelPos -= canvasWidth * 4;
        }

        pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
        y += 1;
        neighborLeft = false;
        neighborRight = false;

        // Go down as long as the color matches and in inside the canvas
        while (y <= (canvasHeight-1) && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
          y += 1;

          setPixel(pixelPos, fillColor.r, fillColor.g, fillColor.b);

          if (x > 0) {
            if (matchStartColor(pixelPos - 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
              if (!neighborLeft) {
                // Add pixel to stack
                pixelStack.push([x - 1, y]);
                neighborLeft = true;
              }
            } else if (neighborLeft) {
              neighborLeft = false;
            }
          }

          if (x < (canvasWidth-1)) {
            if (matchStartColor(pixelPos + 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
              if (!neighborRight) {
                // Add pixel to stack
                pixelStack.push([x + 1, y]);
                neighborRight = true;
              }
            } else if (neighborRight) {
              neighborRight = false;
            }
          }

          pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
        }
      }
    }

    // Fill
    function paintAt(startX, startY) {

      var pixelPos = (startY * canvasWidth + startX) * 4,
        r = fillData.data[pixelPos],
        g = fillData.data[pixelPos + 1],
        b = fillData.data[pixelPos + 2],
        a = fillData.data[pixelPos + 3];

      if (r === fillColor.r && g === fillColor.g && b === fillColor.b) {
        // this one's already filled
        return;
      }

      if (matchstrokeColor(r, g, b, a)) {
        return;
      }

      floodFill(startX, startY, r, g, b);

      redraw();
    }


    function init() {

      var theShapes=document.getElementById("theShapes");
      var theShapesContext=theShapes.getContext("2d");
      drawOutline(theShapesContext);

      drawOutline(context);

      strokeData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      fillData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

      $('#canvas').mousedown(function (e) {
        // Mouse down location
        var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        paintAt(mouseX, mouseY);
      });

      redraw();
    };

    function drawOutline(theContext){   
        theContext.beginPath();
        theContext.moveTo(55, 60);
        theContext.bezierCurveTo(35,  70,  35, 95,  85, 95);
        theContext.bezierCurveTo( 95,110, 130,110, 140, 95);
        theContext.bezierCurveTo(180, 95, 180, 80, 165, 70);
        theContext.bezierCurveTo(185, 40, 155, 35, 140, 45);
        theContext.bezierCurveTo(130, 25,  95, 30,  95, 45);
        theContext.bezierCurveTo( 70, 25,  45, 30,  55, 60);
        theContext.closePath();
        theContext.rect(200,30,100,70);
        theContext.lineWidth = 3;
        theContext.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        theContext.stroke();        
    }

    function getFilledPixelCount(theContext,theCanvas){
        // get the pixel data from the fill canvas
        var imgData=theContext.getImageData(0,0,theCanvas.width,theCanvas.height);
        console.log(imgData.data.length);
        var count=0;
        for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4){
              r = imgData.data[i],
              g = imgData.data[i + 1],
              b = imgData.data[i + 2],
              a = imgData.data[i + 3];
              if (r === fillColor.r && g === fillColor.g && b === fillColor.b) {
                  count++;
              }
          }
        return(count);
    }

    $("#counter").click(function(){alert("There are "+getFilledPixelCount(context,canvas)+" filled pixels.");});

    init();

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>

  </head>
  <body>
        <p>The original stroked shapes</p>
        <canvas id="theShapes" width=350 height=150></canvas><br/>
        <p>The filled shapes used for pixel counting</p>
        <p>Click inside a shape below</p>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=150></canvas><br/>
        <button id="counter">Filled Count</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course this isn't the area enclosed, just all non transparent pixels…

Comment: @Rich Bradshaw--good to meet you! Well, if the shape is filled, it will count the filling and if it's not filled, it won't count the filling--just the stroke :)  But, if OP further requests a pixel count that includes "if-filled" in unfilled shapes--I've got a solution for that too.  It's a bit more complex, but it's basically edge detection that involves identifying all pixels outside the strokes and then subtracting that count from the total pixel count of the canvas.

Comment: That sounds interesting – would be cool to see a demo, I've often wondered how to do edge detection, but most examples are super complex!

Comment: Hi @markE, thanks for posting this. I misinterpreted your initial question — can you post how to go about counting pixels within the outline of an unfilled shape?

Comment: I've posted an edited answer to do your "if-filled" pixel count :)

Comment: @markE, Btw are native GPUs really optimized to do path antialiasing? Why wouldn't HTML5 provide a way to turn it off?